# Fancybox - apply a function to several elements

Tags: jquery, function, fancybox, fancybox-2

This source code below was posted by Cristiano G. Carvalho in answer to the question:
[calling fancybox gallery with other link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9433199/calling-fancybox-gallery-with-other-link/13881264#13881264) made by another user.

```
<div class="details_gallery">
 <a href="#" class="manualfancybox">Manual Call Fancybox</a>
 <div class="details_gallery_min">
  <a rel="details" href="max/1.jpg" class="fancybox"><img src="min/1.jpg" alt="" /></a>
  <a rel="details" href="max/2.jpg" class="fancybox"><img src="min/2.jpg" alt="" /></a>
  <a rel="details" href="max/3.jpg" class="fancybox"><img src="min/3.jpg" alt="" /></a>
  <a rel="details" href="max/4.jpg" class="fancybox"><img src="min/4.jpg" alt="" /></a>
 </div>
</div>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".manualfancybox").click(function() {
        var photos  = new Array();

        $(".details_gallery_min a").each(function(){

            href = $(this).attr("href"); 
            title = $(this).attr("title"); 
            photos.push({'href': href, 'title': title})         

        });

        jQuery.fancybox(photos , 
            {   'transitionIn' : 'elastic', 
                'easingIn' : 'easeOutBack', 
                'transitionOut' : 'elastic', 
                'easingOut' : 'easeInBack', 
                'opacity' : false, 
                'titleShow' : true, 
                'titlePosition' : 'over',
                'type'              : 'image',          
                'titleFromAlt' : true 
            }
        );
    });
});

</script>
```

And it DOES work... if you have ONLY ONE gallery (*.details_gallery_min* in the example).

I've tried to change

```
$(".details_gallery_min a").each(function(){
```

to

```
$(".galleryone a, .gallerytwo a").each(function(){
```

but it only works for ".galleryone a", when I click on the link that calls "gallerytwo" it opens "galleryone". My HTML code is correct.

My question is:

What if I have multiple links opening different galleries and I want to use the same behaviors (transition, easing, etc.) to all galleries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, while [Cristiano G. Carvalho](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13881264/1055987)'s answer works, I think it is overdoing things. The `array()` + the `.each()` method will have a(n) (arguable) high cost in terms of memory and performance, much more if you have several images in your galleries.

I don't see any reason to iterate through every element and build the fancybox gallery (again) inside an array if a simple fancybox code and manual event handlers can tackle the issue. But that is entirely my personal opinion.

So for instance, if you have an html like this :

```
<h3>gallery one</h3>
<div id="gallery_one">
    <a rel="galleryone" class="fancybox" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_b.jpg"><img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_s.jpg" alt=""/></a>
    <a rel="galleryone" class="fancybox" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/2_b.jpg"><img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/2_s.jpg" alt=""/></a>
... etc.
</div>

<h3>gallery two</h3>
<div id="gallery_two">
    <a rel="gallerytwo" class="fancybox" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/3_b.jpg"><img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/3_s.jpg" alt=""/></a>
    <a rel="gallerytwo" class="fancybox" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/4_b.jpg"><img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/4_s.jpg" alt=""/></a>
...etc.
</div>
```

Rewriting my [own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9435929/1055987) to the same question, I would set any manual links I need like :

```
<a class="manualfancybox" data-gallery="gallery_one" href="#nogo">manual call to first gallery</a>
<a class="manualfancybox" data-gallery="gallery_two" href="#nogo">manual call to second gallery</a>
```

**Notice** that I added an HTML5 `data-gallery` attribute that indicates what gallery the link is targeting to (the `data-gallery` value matches the ID of the parent container of each gallery)

Then, add the fancybox code for all galleries

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    // API options here
});
```

and bind the event handler to the manual fancybox calls like :

```
$(".manualfancybox").on("click", function(){
    var gallery = "#" + $(this).data("gallery");
    $(gallery).find(".fancybox").eq(0).click();
    return false;
});
```

Set the value of `.eq()` depending on what image the gallery should start from.

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/uzsdX/)**

**NOTE** : `.on()` requires jQuery v1.7+

Comment: I saw your answer there earlier before asking, but wasn't able to implement it to work along with my needs.

Your code is so much more simpler and smooth than the one I was using.

I'm very impressed, and I hope it can help others too. Thank you.