# Fancybox force load first image (index), not working as expected

Tags: jquery, indexing, fancybox, fancybox-2

I am using custom next and previous to allow the user to navigate between multiple fancybox galleries, which works well. However -- when navigating between galleries, for some reason fancybox automatically selects the last image in the gallery.

I need to add a way to force fancybox to always load the first gallery image when it's initiated. By default, the index IS set to 0, which is a little confusing as to why it'd be changing.

Ideas? Here's my code.

Here is the code I'm working with:

```
var $thisFancyRel = 0;
var $itemsPerPage = 9;
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    index : 0,
    helpers : {
        title   : {
            type: 'outside'
        },
        thumbs  : {
            width   : 50,
            height  : 50
        }
    },
    afterLoad : function() {
        var $self = $(this.element);
        $thisFancyRel = parseInt($($self).attr("rel"));
    },
    afterShow : function() {
        $button_next = "<div class='gallery__next'>Next</div>";
        $button_prev = "<div class='gallery__prev'>Previous</div>";
        $button_clear = "<div class='clearboth'></div>";
        if($thisFancyRel > 0) {
            if($thisFancyRel == 1) {
                $buttons = $button_next + $button_clear;
            } else if ($thisFancyRel == $itemsPerPage) {
                $buttons = $button_prev + $button_clear;
            } else {
                $buttons = $button_prev + $button_next + $button_clear;
            }
        }
        $(".fancybox-skin").after($buttons);
    },
    beforeClose : function() {
        $thisFancyRel = 0;
    }
});
$(document).on("click", ".gallery__next", function () {
    var $nextFancyRel = $thisFancyRel + 1;
    if($nextFancyRel > 0) {
        var $relName = '.fancybox[rel="' + $nextFancyRel + '"]';
        $.fancybox.close();
        $($relName).trigger('click');
    }
});
$(document).on("click", ".gallery__prev", function () {
    var $prevFancyRel = $thisFancyRel - 1;
    if($prevFancyRel > 0) {
        var $relName = '.fancybox[rel="' + $prevFancyRel + '"]';
        $.fancybox.close();
        $($relName).trigger('click');   
    }
});
```

Comment: try `$($relName).eq(0).trigger('click')` instead. BTW, if triggering a new gallery, you don't need to close fancybox so you can delete `$.fancybox.close();` (opening a new instance will close the opened fancybox if any)

Comment: Phew. So relieved. Been working on that one too long. Worked perfectly. Thanks! (If you'd like, throw your solution on there so I can mark it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `index` option works if you start your gallery directly from the anchor bound to fancybox.

On the other hand, if you start your gallery manually or using another element as a trigger, then the gallery will start from the last element found.

You can use the `.eq()` method to start the gallery from the first item (or any other element) so try this in your code

```
$($relName).eq(0).trigger('click')
```

You may also see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/9435929/1055987 for reference.

BTW, if triggering a new gallery, you don't need to close fancybox so you can delete `$.fancybox.close();` (opening a new instance will close the opened fancybox if any)