# FancyBox V3 Beta : Open Gallery with Thumbnails from other Image Link Without Having It Used Inside

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm using the V3 Beta 1 version of FancyBox (http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/beta/).

I'm able to open a gallery **with thumbnails** from a **single small image link** with code such as below :

```
<div class="imglist">
    <a class="fancybox-Test" rel="fancybox-Test" href="pix1.jpg" title="my title 1"><img src="small_image_to_present_gallery.png" alt="ALT_TITLE"></a>

    <span style="display:none">
  <a class="fancybox-Test" rel="fancybox-Test" href="pix2.jpg" title="my title 2"><img src="" alt="ALT_TITLE"></a>
        <a class="fancybox-Test" rel="fancybox-Test" href="pix3.jpg" title="my title 3"><img src="" alt="ALT_TITLE"></a>
        <a class="fancybox-Test" rel="fancybox-Test" href="pix4.jpg" title="my title 4"><img src="" alt="ALT_TITLE"></a>
</span>
</div>
```

**Problem with above code is that single small image presenting the whole gallery** (small_image_to_present_gallery.png) **is then used as thumbnail for the first image (pix1.jpg) once gallery opened.**

In other words I would like to be able to open a gallery with thumbnails from link of any other image (ie not linked with gallery content).

Is there a way to do this (easily) please ?

I read the "Tips & tricks" section (http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/ - "Start the gallery with only one preview picture") but this is not the same problem as it does not use thumbnails.

Tx.
Tom

Comment: Solution found here :
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9433199/calling-fancybox-gallery-with-other-link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9433199/calling-fancybox-gallery-with-other-link